# Neo4j relationship changes over time in an medieval database

Tags: datetime, neo4j, relationships

I'm an medieval historian and trying to create a neo4j Database with Persons from the 13th century and their relationships changing over time. The relations are created from informations from charters and so they have a starting date with the date of the charter and they end three years after the date of the charter (which is a personal chosen value from me and can be changed for research purposes). But if there is a charter in between these 3 years i want to update the type of the relationship.
At the moment I have no idea how to code over-time-changing relationships in neo4j.
I'm importing the nodes and edges from csv-Tables and at the moment i have about 7000 relationships.
Any ideas out there ?

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to build the proper relationships from your data (with the rules you stated) in which case you would end with a static graph once all is done and said. Or do you wish to have a graph on which the traversals will change depending on some arbitrary input date at the start of the traversal?

Comment: I think the second case is what i need.

Comment: You could just encode that with a different property value on the relationship. To change a relationship-type you'd have to recreate it with a different type.

Comment: Otherwise this approach might be interesting: http://www.slideshare.net/ophileon/graphrica-keeping-track-of-changes-in-project-logic-for-de

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand what the slides mean ? Would be very thankful for some advice ?